# Facebook graph api, get gender of friends

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, express, pug

I'm trying to breakup my list of friends by gender but I don't know how to get the the friends gender from their id and list the friends by gender. Currently I have their id and profile pic listed. Essentially all I need is how to get their gender and sort the friends.

```
     for friend in friends
  .col-xs-3.col-md-2
    p #{friend.id}
    a.thumbnail(href='http://facebook.com/#{friend.id}')
      img(src='https://graph.facebook.com/#{friend.id}/picture?width=150&height=150')





 exports.getFacebook = function(req, res, next) {
 var token = _.find(req.user.tokens, { kind: 'facebook' });
 graph.setAccessToken(token.accessToken);
 async.parallel({
getMe: function(done) {
  graph.get(req.user.facebook, function(err, me) {
    done(err, me);
  });
},
getMyFriends: function(done) {
  graph.get(req.user.facebook + '/friends', function(err, friends) {
    done(err, friends.data);
  });
}
 },
 function(err, results) {
if (err) return next(err);
res.render('api/facebook', {
  title: 'Facebook API',
  me: results.getMe,
  friends: results.getMyFriends
});
});
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your `getMyFriends` function make an API call to `graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=name,gender`

Each item in the response will look something like

```
{
      "name": "phwd", 
      "gender": "male", 
      "id": "113702895386410"
}
```

From there you can break it up.

You can also do `/FRIEND_ID?fields=name,gender`

These calls will of course have to be appended with an access token or be returned via an SDK call.